# How to convert VS assembly to gcc assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly, porting

I am porting some code from Visual Studio to Linux. In Linux the GCC compiler is not able to add immediate values to labels.

Visual Studio:

```
int main()
{
one:
   goto done;
two:
  goto done;

   uint32_t offset = 0x10; // assume address between two labels is 16.

    __asm
    {
    mov eax, ONE
    add eax, offset
    jmp eax
    }

done:
   return;
}
```

GCC: (what I tried)

```
int main()
{
one:
   goto done;
two:
  goto done;

    asm goto ("jmp %l0\n"  : /* no output */ : /* no input */ : /* no clobber*/ : one);

done:
   return;
}
```

I'm not able to increment the label in gcc. Help me to how to increment the label in gcc

Comment: Don't use assembly for that. See [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) in the manual instead or describe what you want to achieve so we can offer a better solution.

Comment: Um, Visual Studio isn't capable of doing it either. The Visual Studio version calculates the sum at runtime. Do the same for the gcc version.

Comment: *assume address between two labels is 16.* Well that's just based on nothing at all.  You could probably `add $%l1 - %l0, %[target]`  where you had a RMW register input that you can destroy, to get the assembler to calculate the distance between the two target labels.  Doing this in inline asm is just asking for trouble, though; what problem are you really trying to solve where the compiler doesn't make efficient asm on its own with `-O3 -march=native`?

Comment: Your Visual Studio example doesn't even compile with Visual Studio, and if it did it wouldn't actually do anything.